Why Oracle JDK 13 is available but not corretto 13
Why Oracle JDK 13 is available but not corretto 13 from AWS?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/ - Shows version 11 and then 17.
Is there any way to get this?

Oracle provides access to all of their old (end-of-life) releases.  AWS apparently doesn't.  Or at least not via >that< URL.  But even with Oracle, you have to go digging into the archive download area to find the old stuff, so I'm not sure there's a substantial difference.

Actually, I have a feeling that Corretto 13 never existed.  On the Corretto Github account (https://github.com/orgs/corretto) there are repos for 8, 11, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 and 23.  Some of these are "archived", but in all of them you can find download links for the builds.  There is nothing between 11 and 17.  When I Google for "Corretto 13" I can't find any relevant results ... apart from this Q&A :-).

But as the answer says, you shouldn't be using Java 13 anyway.  It's dead Jim.

JDK 13 was a Short Term Support release (STS) that was only supported for a few months. It is available from Oracle download archive. There is absolutely no reason why anyone should try to use end of life STS releases other than the current one, if you are experimenting with bleeding edge features. JDK 11, 17 and 21 are Long Term Support releases that are supported for a longer period of time and which are strongly recommended to use.
